dns works and nft http counters rise: no webpage shows :404
0.The main problem is the nft counters increase but no web page shows. Claims http 404 error.

DNS and dig report valid results.From inet firewalld filter_INPUT:
'''meta l4proto {tcp,udp} ct state established,related ct original proto-dst {53,5353} @th,80,16 0x8180 ip length >192 counter log'''.
https and http are recognized seemingly by:[browser shows only 404 error]
'''ct state established,related ct original proto-dst 443 counter name "httpsrecv" accept'''.

nftrace is not installed nor is strace and nft monitor trace cannot seem to absorb "ct original proto-dst x" easily.
I have used similar rules on fedora41 with no problems. Fedora41 however could not run VirtualBox and compiling my own copy yielded the exact same problem . I did compile my own kernel but nothing on fedora 41 would work.
Under fedora 40 using a 'linux admin' suppled DVD I also get  20k-30k https packets but that is a separate

What is the question? I see symptoms, but I don't get what actually bothers you in it.

The title lpoints out I'm getting a 404 withered rules ..why?

Well, how did you see 404? Try to get this error when using curl against the same URL, and show us both the command line and its output. Also, if you're getting HTTP status 404, it could only mean that the web server replied. Then there must be some server logs. Also, 4xx is a "bad request" type of error, so there must be record in both access log and error log. So, show us relevant log records, together with the web server configuration.
